# OpenFST Create Morphological Analyzer

Tags: nlp, openfst

I want to create a morphological analyzer (only for suffixes) for English language with OpenFST.
For example,

> Input: computerization
>
> Output:  compute + -er + -ize + -ation + Noun

My question is how should I create input and output symbols using shell commands. Is there a way to do this in OpenFST?